# Azure Notification Hub Templates - Dynamic Template

Tags: c#, azure, azure-notificationhub

In my push notifications, I have dynamic parameters that I can send.  I can do this with a regular notification and create my payload dynamically.  But I would like to use templates for this since I need to send to iOS, android and WP.  For example :

```
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)','url':'/test/test'}}";
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)','action':'delete'}}";
```

So I'm trying to register a dynamic template for android like so, but I'm not sure if this is possible :

```
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)',$(params)}}";
registration = new GcmTemplateRegistrationDescription(deviceToken, payloadAndroid);
```

And then, I would use these parameters :

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictionary.Add("message", "My message test");
dictionary.Add("icon", "icon.png");
dictionary.Add("params", "'url':'/test/index.aspx','action':'myaction'");

hub.SendTemplateNotificationAsync(dictionary, "myTag");
```

This throws an XmlException, but was wondering if anyone have another solution for this?

I have also tried these, same exeption :

```
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)',{$(params)}}}";
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)',#(params)}}";
```

I don't want to add all my possible parameters in the payload since they come from a db, can change and the payload might get too big for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Template payload should be a valid JSON otherwise client validation fails. Try this:

"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(message)\",\"icon\":\"$(icon)\",\"url\":\"$(url)\",\"action\":\"$(action)\"}}"

Then sending a message you could specify "delete" for action and "" for url or vice versa.

Comment: Like I said in the question, I can't add all my parameters like this, because I have to many and they are dynamic.

Comment: I see... Looks like templates don't work for you in current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested this, you could try something like this, given that you can guarantee a maximum number of parameters:

```
var payloadAndroid = "{'data':{'message':'$(message)','icon':'$(icon)','param1':'$(param1)','param2':'$(param2)','param3':'$(param3)'}}";
```

I assume this will work with different number of parameters and the parameters that you don't provide will be just empty/null. Otherwise you could try to register multiple templates, each with a different number of parameters...

Comment: thanks, interesting solution, I will try with multiple templates.